# Obtaining a Digital Certificate

Tags: certificate, clickonce, code-signing, digital-certificate

We have a .net WPF application running as both XBAP and Desktop etc.I haven't signed any assemblies etc.My question is that

Q1.What kind of Digital Certificate do I need to purchase from VeriSign, Inc., or another certificate authority. to sign my application,use it as Authenticode Certificate (in clickonce) ?

Q2.Can I use this Digital Certificate to sign other applications like installers,assemblies,pdf etc?

Q3.Is one Digital  Certificate enough for a company or I have to buy other?

Q4.What happens when the Certificate expires? (So is it better to not have it and screw yourself if no one is gonna hack and plant a virus in you app folder or something ???)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A1. You need a code signing certificate. They come in several flavours, and typically can be converted from one to the other, but it's probably easiest to get an Authenticode one rightaway.

A2. You can use the same cert to sign installers and assemblies (and any .EXE, .DLL, .OCX file). I think the same applies to .PDF, but I've never used that.

A3. I'd go for a single cert for your company.

A4. When the cert expires, you cannot use it for signing anymore. However, as long as you use a [timestamping service](https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/code-signing-support/index?page=content&id=AR190) when you sign your code, already signed files remain valid.

Answer (score 1):

A1: You need code signing certificate. You may choose any provider, but do notice that not all of them are recognized by Windows as "trusted". Among trusted and cheaper ones (cheaper then VeriSign) there is [Comodo](http://www.comodo.com/).

A2: Yes.

A3: One is enough.

A4: You will not be able to sign new code. Old code will remain signed if you used timestamp server (you'll get location of one with certificate). If you opt not to use timestamp server, certification will remain valid, but users will get message that it it expired.